# BroadcastChannel testing in chrome developer tools console isn't working

Tags: javascript, broadcast-channel

I am testing the [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) functionality and I'am having trouble. I open two Chrome windows and the dev tools for each. On the console I write:

```
const z = new BroadcastChannel('blarg')
z.onmessage = function (ev) {console.log(ev)}
```

I can examine z and it has the function saved to the onmessage prop so it all looks good. However, when I test:

```
z.postMessage('sweet')
```

in one of the consoles, nothing shows in the other. I would expect since both Chrome windows are subscribed to the broadcast channel `blarg` and have a function to console log the message that is posted, I would see the message `sweet` to be shown in the other console but nothing happens.

So two questions:

Can't I test `BroadcastChannel` interface in the devtools console like this?

If so, what am I missing about how BroadcastChannel works?

Comment: From what context are you testing this? Are both page served from the same domain? Are you on a `file://` page?

Answer (score 2):

It works if:

1. the communication happens on the same origin
2. the channel name is the same on both ends (`blarg` in your case, but it could also be `""`)
3. you don't expect to receive the message if you are the sender

When you say

> I open two chrome windows and the dev tools for each.

call them `A` and `B`. In nomenclature `A` and `B` are defined as "browsing contexts", and they could also be tabs, frames or iframes.

The following code is an example that satisfies conditions 1. and 2.

devtools `A`:

```
location.href = 'https://example.com'
z = new BroadcastChannel('blarg')
z.onmessage = (ev) => { console.log(ev) }
```

devtools `B`:

```
location.href = 'https://example.com'
z = new BroadcastChannel('blarg')
z.onmessage = (ev) => { console.log(ev) }
```

Condition 1 is also satisfied when browser contexts (windows, tabs, frames or iframes) don't "point" to any regular url (for example when you press CTRL+T to open a new tab). In this case the origin has the special value of `chrome://new-tab-page`.

Said that, if you post from `A` to `B`, `B` will receive the message and `console.log` it. The same applies vice versa.